# Why is 14 (board numbering system) listed as a GPIO pin, and not 13?

Tags: gpio, python, rpi.gpio

```
>>> RPIO.RPI_REVISION
2
>>> RPIO.GPIO_LIST_R2
(2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 17, 18, 22, 23, 24, 25, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31)
```

Pin 14 is ground, shouldn't this be pin 13 instead?

[image: pins]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## GPIO.BCM Pin 14

BCM Pin 14 is GPIO. There is no GPIO.BCM pin 13.

### Header Pin 13 / 14

Header Pin P1-13 = GPIO2 / BCM Pin Rv1: 21, Rv2: 27
Header Pin P1-14 = Ground.

You may be getting Header Pin / BCM Pin mixed up. The numbers down the centre are Header Pin Numbers e.g. 3|4   5|6. Any more questions just ask.

Comment: Yes, but RPIO should be handling the conversion from the header pin number scheme (`RPIO.BOARD`) to BCM (or whichever RPi uses internally—ideally I shouldn't need to care). Should I be looking at `RPIO.GPIO_LIST_R.` as pins under the BCM scheme?

Answer (score 4):

The [RPIO website](http://pythonhosted.org/RPIO/rpio_py.html) says it "uses the BCM GPIO numbering scheme by default". See my answer to [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12966/what-is-the-difference-between-board-and-bcm-for-gpio-pin-numbering) for the difference.

As @JamesClarke says, these are the `BCM` numbers of the GPIO pins. The 4 extra pins (28,29,30,31) that aren't in our diagrams came into use in revision 2.0 [on the new P5 header interface](http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals#P5_header), next to the main header plug.

Comment: Can't believe I missed the very first line of the docs. I've been pouring over those for the past two days! Thanks!