# Simple LED code says that object has no attribute output?

Tags: gpio, python, rpi.gpio, led

I installed RPi.GPIO .5.1 and my uber basic led code says that the object has no attribute 'output'.  I am hooking up the 12 pin to the Breadboard and I have ground hooked up too. [Here](http://pastebin.com/WfCwkWse) is my python 2.7.7 code:

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(12,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(12,GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(3)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What errors result when you run the script?

Here are a few potential errors I can see:

- you could use `from time import sleep` instead of `import time`
- you haven't put in the [shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) at the start of the script (`#!/usr/bin/env python`) - this tells what you are using to run it what it is.
- You likely don't need `GPIO.output(12,GPIO.LOW)` as I would of thought that `GPIO.output(12,GPIO.HIGH)` would override it (you can also use `GPIO.output(12, True)`
- With the `GPIO.setup(GPIO.OUT)` line, I think you need to specify the pin number - so it would be `GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)`

Another problem could be that you don't have it wired correctly - you can get help with pin numbers etc [here](http://elinux.org/FR:RPi_Low-level_peripherals#General_Purpose_Input.2FOutput_.28GPIO.29). Try not get confused between the [Board and BCM numbering](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12966/what-is-the-difference-between-board-and-bcm-for-gpio-pin-numbering)

So something like this should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(12, True))
print "On"
sleep(3)
print "Off"
GPIO.output(11, False)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: How did this solve your problem ? I have the same one and cannot figure out from where this comes from

Comment: @ypicard what error - "*has no attribute 'output'.*" ? I guess it could the the extra `)` in the code above otherwise...

Answer (score 0):

This error 'module' object has no attribute 'output' means that the library which can access GPIO is not installed in it
so, open your terminal

type: `$ sudo apt-get install python-rpi.gpio python3-rpi.gpio`

and then run your program if any warning occurs then add `GPIO.setwarnings(False)` to your code

Comment: `the library which can access GPIO is not installed in it ` if that is the case then why does the script not crash at import or the calls to setmode and setup. Anyway, the previous answer was accepted as an answer so it apparently solved the problem.