# There is a problem with my python source

Tags: python, raspivid

i received a lot of help to the Raspberry Pi study for yours
thank you so much!! :)

but there is a problem to me.

i hope as follow 
1. The record run
2. If the vibration sensor is detected during the recording, 
   the recording should stop running
3. and the recording starts and againg in a different title.

Python source under are as follows
vibration detect -> the picture are taken

Beneath the source is not a problem. but i don't know how to code the recording source...

ex) camera.start_recording("123.h264")
    camera.wait_recording(24*60*60)
    camera.stop_recording()          ->>>   is only recorded.
    During recording, the sensor is not detected..

What should i do...??
   I've continued to find on Google, did not find....

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import datatime
import picamera
from time import sleep

count=0
GPIO.setup(6, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
sleep(0.1)

camera = picamera.PiCamera()

while True:
   now = datetime.datetime.now()
   result = GPIO.input(6)
   if result == 1:
      print("Vibrated".count)
      count+=1
      camera.capture("%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d.jpg' &(now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour, now.minute, now.second)
```

Comment: Where is .count being defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well firstly you have not defined the pin mode which is how it tells if you want a physical number (1-40) to define your pin with or the [Broadcom SOC channel numbering](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12966/what-is-the-difference-between-board-and-bcm-for-gpio-pin-numbering). You can change this with `GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)` or, `GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)`. Also according to [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RPi.GPIO/0.3.1a) the RPiGPIO module is unsuitable for real time or critical timing applications which is kinda what your doing with the camera reacting to the sensor.