# 7 color flash sensor does not blink

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, led

I have a raspberry pi 2 Model B v1.1 and 7 color flash sensor. I want to flash the led to get my hand into practice. This is my first program with raspberry pi and unfortunately i failed to flash the led.

I am not using breadboard. I am using pi pin. For that i have used three female-female wire. One for connecting to 5v, one to ground and one to 11 number pin as a channel for supplying high or low voltage so when i use GPIO.output(11,True) led will flash. But it is not working. Here is my code.

**7colorflash.py**

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time



GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
mode = GPIO.getmode()
if mode == GPIO.BOARD:
    GPIO.setup(12,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(12,True)
    GPIO.output(12,False)
elif mode == GPIO.BCM:
    GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(12,True)
    GPIO.output(12,False)
else:
    print('None')
GPIO.cleanup()
```

I have attached an image to show the connection. wire connected to 5v is in number 2 pin, ground in number 6 pin and channel number 11 is used.

[image]

What might be the cause for not flashing the led?

Comment: Are you sure this device is safe to connect to a 3V3 GPIO.  Where are its specs?

Comment: 343 GPIO? Sorry i did not get you

Comment: The device is powered by 5V, but the GPIO pins output 3.3V logic.  You need to find out if the device is compatible with that.

Comment: oh sorry its my mistake I wrote number 1 pin in the question but i have connected it to number 2 pin and is not working. Sorry for my mistake in question.

Comment: **Where are the 7 color flash sensor specifications?**

Comment: "Connected to pin number 2" -> If you are still talking about the power that's not the issue.  The issue is *the GPIO pin*, which you've referred to as 11.  That's a 3.3V signal.  If you do not have the specs and cannot identify the device but have everything else right, then this is likely the problem.

Comment: @goldilocks Sir i am using Raspberry PI 3 model and did the connection correctly. Setup 1 -> Problem which i am facing is when i connect LED to pin 11 without connecting it to pin 1 the light which i get from the LED after running the code is very low after running the code. Setup 2 -> On the other hand when i connect it to pin 1 along with pin 11 and GND i am getting continuous light from the led flash with high brightness which seems like the python code won't work at all for the second setup.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of the following.

- Broken LED
- Not connected to pin 11
- Not driving the LED according to its specifications
- LED connected back to front

Comment: I have updated my question with image to show connection.

Comment: LED is a new one, though. I have bought 37 in 1 sensor kit and its used just today.

Answer (score 0):

As [per this](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/BasicUsage/), there are two commonplace ways of conceiving of the board pin numbers.  Based on your photograph, you are assuming the `BOARD` numbering scheme, but you have not actually specified one way or the other.

While it says there setting that is mandatory, it could be importing the module under an alias (`GPIO`) sets it for you (or there actually is a default and setting it isn't so "mandatory").  I do not use python so don't know. You should try an if/else clause to test the value of `GPIO.getmode()` against `GPIO.BOARD`, `GPIO.BCM`, or `None` to see which it is.

If it is `GPIO.BCM` that is not pin 11, that is pin 18 (or perhaps 17, if you started counting from 1, it is hard to tell which row that connection is on).

Comment: so before setting the mode i have to do GPIO.getmode(). If mode == GPIO.BOARD i have to use number 11 pin as a channel and if mode equals to BCM use channel 17 ?

Comment: Presuming you were counting from 1 and that connection is the inside row yes.  This is about the number you would use in the code when the connector is where it is now.  There's a diagram and more explanation here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/12966/5538

Comment: I have now used 12 pin(BOARD) and 18 for BCM. Still it is not working. If i did not set GPIO at first before getmode() i get an error. With above code it is not working too.

Comment: Then unless you can determine what logic level the device is compatible with it is probably because it is supposed to be used with 5V *logic*.  The logic level and the supply power are not necessarily the same, but if they are, then that device won't work directly with the Pi, because while it has a few 5V pins to provide *power*, the logic of the GPIOs is 3.3V.  Devices/sensors sold for the Arduino are usually 5V logic...

Comment: ...Sometimes they are sold "for the Arduino or Raspberry Pi" but this is ambiguous -- it could mean they work with either, but it could also be sneaky in that in fact a level shifter or something similar is actually needed for one or the other.  More about that here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/49775/5538