# Selecting GPIO pins for multiple MCP4725 DACs

Tags: pi-3, gpio, python, i2c

I'm doing a project in which I need to use DAC-s to conduct voltage to dimmers to switch appliances on or off.

So far I've used [Adafruit's guide](https://learn.adafruit.com/mcp4725-12-bit-dac-with-raspberry-pi/configuring-your-pi-for-i2c) and it worked fine. I got the I2C working 
and `sudo i2cdetect -y 1` showed my DACs to be at 0x62. It also worked when testing the setup with the `simpletest.py`.

The next issue I'm facing is that there are 4 DACs and I need to be able to give each of them a separate value.

Here are the schemas:

[image: Scheme_1]
[image]

As I understand I need to use these:

- SEL1(GPIO pin 12)
- SEL2(GPIO pin 11)
- SEL3(GPIO pin 16)
- SEL4(GPIO pin 18)

to access the I2C "slaves" and change their addresses according to [this](https://learn.adafruit.com/i2c-addresses/overview), another Adafruit guide.

How would I go about doing this in e.g. changing the [Adafruit code](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_MCP4725/blob/master/Adafruit_MCP4725/MCP4725.py) to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure only one device has I2C address 0x62 at any one time.

```
SEL1(GPIO pin 12)
SEL2(GPIO pin 11)
SEL3(GPIO pin 16)
SEL4(GPIO pin 18)
```

Initially set each of the pins high so that each device is at I2C address 0x63.

When you want to access a device set its pin low.  That device will now be at address 0x62 and may be accessed through I2C.  When you have finished with the device set its pin high.

Only one of the device pins must be low at any one time.

Comment: Something like this [link](https://codeshare.io/aynjlz)?

The problem is, I only have my RPi at home. Multimeter, the DACs and everything else are at the site, where I will get to go tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, that is doing as I described.

Comment: To expand on this, Joan's instructions were helpful and led me to the result I hoped to achieve. Although I struggled with a newbie problem when setting the pins high or low.

`GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)`
and
`GPIO.setmode(GPIO.board)`

are quite different. [Here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12966/what-is-the-difference-between-board-and-bcm-for-gpio-pin-numbering) is a good explanation.